# Controlling log size in Spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

We have Spark streaming job running in HDInsight Spark cluster (yarn mode) and we are seeing the streaming job stopping after few weeks due to what looks like running out of disk space due to log volume.

Is there a way to set limit on log size for Spark streaming job and enable rolling log? I have tried setting the below spark executor log properties in code, but this setting doesn’t seem to be honored.

```
val sparkConfiguration: SparkConf = EventHubsUtils.initializeSparkStreamingConfigurations

sparkConfiguration.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles", "2")
sparkConfiguration.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxSize", "107374182")

val spark = SparkSession
                     .builder
                     .config(sparkConfiguration)
                     .getOrCreate()
```